# Send data to App when data changed in Firebase Database in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building an App where I would like to generate a Push Notification for the user when a data has been changed in the Firebase Realtime Database. I would like to know if using Firebase Cloud Messaging is appropriate for it and would love some idea about how the FCM is used to send data to the App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [script](https://github.com/azizur-rehman/SSTalk/blob/master/Cloud%20Script/index.js) I wrote for sending notification when a change is triggered here

Comment: The question is for Android.

Comment: Yeah well, but there are certain things you cannot do while holding a single knot.

Comment: Or the wrong knot for that matter :P

Comment: The question ```Push Notification for the user when a data has been changed in the Firebase Realtime Database``` is what the script has. So how come its the wrong knot? Perhaps you might wanna check out the repo, its actually meant for an android app.

Comment: No offence at all. The question pretty much defined that a solution for Android is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use value listener to listen and send notification on data changes, example:

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Send notification here
        FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
                .getHttpsCallable("sendNotification")
                .call(notificationData)
                .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                        return null;
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

In the function:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    // I am using FCM Topic to send notification to users.
    var fcmTopic = data.fcmTopic;
    console.log(data);

    var payload = {
        data:{
            MESSAGE_TAG: "NEW_NOTIF",
            MESSAGE_TITLE: "Test!",
            MESSAGE_TEXT: "Test."
        },
        topic: fcmTopic
    };

    var options = {
        priority: "high"
    };

    admin.messaging().send(payload)
        .then(() => {
            console.log("success");
            return null;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });


});
```

More info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Comment: It's an android app :) not node-js, however the solution is the right one

Comment: Should use database trigger instead

Comment: How will it work for triggering the right user? Means will I have to keep a check of that too.

Comment: Yes you have to keep track of either a registration token or topic for the user to send notification/

Comment: I've added a sample firebase function to send notification.

Comment: bad idea to use FCM for this, use listeners, they are meant for your use case

Comment: Listeners can be used to listen to data changes, FCM is needed to send the notification.